# Merge two correlation tables into a symmetrical named matrix

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

Good morning,

I'm looking for a way to programmatically transform two different dataframes (with correlation coefficients) into one symmetrical named matrix with values from one dataframe in the upper triangle and data of the other dataframe in the lower triangle.

Take two correlational tables:

```
t1<-structure(list(var1 = c("SE", "SE", "CN", "GN", "CN", "CN"), 
                   var2 = c("VN", "GN", "SE", "VN", "VN", "GN"), cor = c("-0.42***", 
                                                                         "0.16***", "-0.21***", "0.1**", "0.35***", "0.07*")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                   -6L))

t2<-structure(list(var1 = c("SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "VN", "VN", "VN", 
                            "GN", "GN", "CN"), var2 = c("VN", "GN", "CN", "IS", "GN", "CN", 
                                                        "IS", "CN", "IS", "IS"), cor = c("-0.41***", "0.14***", "-0.02", 
                                                                                         "0.28***", "0.1**", "0.28***", "-0.02", "0.03", "-0.06†", "0.53***"
                                                        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

`t1` is a correlation table of `X=4` variables:

```
  var1 var2      cor
1   SE   VN -0.42***
2   SE   GN  0.16***
3   CN   SE -0.21***
4   GN   VN    0.1**
5   CN   VN  0.35***
6   CN   GN    0.07*
```

`t2` is a correlation table with `X + 1` variables (same names as in `X` + 1 more)

```
   var1 var2      cor
1    SE   VN -0.41***
2    SE   GN  0.14***
3    SE   CN    -0.02
4    SE   IS  0.28***
5    VN   GN    0.1**
6    VN   CN  0.28***
7    VN   IS    -0.02
8    GN   CN     0.03
9    GN   IS   -0.06†
10   CN   IS  0.53***
```

**I'd like to:**

- make a symmetrical matrix from `t2` data
- replace the upper triangle with corresponding `t1` data
- remove last column (that is redundant)

[image]

I know I could do it by hand but I have many datasets to process with varying size matrices (and names) and tables like the above that should be reported.

My manual solution is as follows:

```
mat <- matrix(NA, 5,4, dimnames = list(c("SE", "VN", "GN", "CN", "IS"),
                                       c("SE", "VN", "GN", "CN")))
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- t2$cor
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- t1$cor
diag(mat) <- "-"
mat
   SE         VN         GN         CN       
SE "-"        "-0.42***" "0.16***"  "0.1**"  
VN "-0.41***" "-"        "-0.21***" "0.35***"
GN "0.14***"  "0.1**"    "-"        "0.07*"  
CN "-0.02"    "0.28***"  "0.03"     "-"      
IS "0.28***"  "-0.02"    "-0.06†"   "0.53***"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only part you need to make dynamic is the names. This can be done as follows,

```
unique(c(t(t1[1:2])))
#[1] "SE" "VN" "GN" "CN"
unique(c(t(t2[1:2])))
#[1] "SE" "VN" "GN" "CN" "IS"
```

So to make it a generalised function,

```
f1 <- function(df1, df2) {
    col <- unique(c(t(df1[1:2])))
    rn <- unique(c(t(df2[1:2])))
    mat <- matrix(NA, length(rn), length(col), dimnames = list(rn, col))
    mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- df2$cor
    mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- df1$cor
    diag(mat) <- "-"
    return(mat)
}

f1(t1, t2)
#   SE         VN         GN         CN       
#SE "-"        "-0.42***" "0.16***"  "0.1**"  
#VN "-0.41***" "-"        "-0.21***" "0.35***"
#GN "0.14***"  "0.1**"    "-"        "0.07*"  
#CN "-0.02"    "0.28***"  "0.03"     "-"      
#IS "0.28***"  "-0.02"    "-0.06†"   "0.53***"
```